# Message size quota

Tags: wcf, maxreceivedmessagesize

My WCF service is throwing an error when it returns a large amount of data.  I'm testing from the WCF Test Client so there is no client config file.  The Invoke works properly when it's asked to return a smaller data set.  I've read every post here about this problem and they all say to do what I've already done.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Here is my app.config:

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="FAPWCF.FAPService">
        <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="FAPWCF.IFAPService">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8732/Design_Time_Addresses/FAPWCF/Service1/" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>

    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding allowCookies="true" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"/>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>

    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, 
          set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True" />
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, 
          set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment 
          to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: Exception details would be helpful.

Comment: The maximum message size quota for incoming messages (65536) has been exceeded. To increase the quota, use the MaxReceivedMessageSize property on the appropriate binding element.

<lots of stack trace info>

The maximum message size quota for incoming messages (65536) has been exceeded. To increase the quota, use the MaxReceivedMessageSize property on the appropriate binding element.

Comment: I found it, the problem was in the Config file of the WCF Test Client.  There is a way to modify it from within the client.  When I did that it worked with my largest dataset.  And you can instruct the WCF Test Client to not regenerate a new config file each time it's run so that the changes will be perpetuated.  I don't know if the "don't regenerate" applies to every WCF project that starts the test client or only the one I'm in now.